# macro to autofill columns when new row added?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a tracker that I built to observe the movement of certain items. There are 2 things I am looking to accomplish, both to take place when a **new row is added to the worksheet**:

1. have the XLOOKUP formula that lives in and sets the value of column A be automatically applied to the new row so it doesn't have to be copied/dragged down. the formula works great, and the range the data is based on doesn’t change. but with each new row added, the row of the B cell referenced will change. current formula is:

- for cell A2 `=XLOOKUP(B2,Subledgers!$B$3:$B$58,Subledgers!$C$3:$C$58)`

2. have the status (column L) set to match the name of the worksheet when a new row is added in that worksheet

a majority of new rows added will be done so in the worksheet labeled 'Outstanding', and then moved to their appropriate tabs based on the tracking. so if it is easier to apply these edits strictly to that worksheet, that would be fine.

*A current macro is in place to move the entire row to the appropriate worksheet based on the status selected. As far as I can tell, it works perfectly and does everything I need it to, but if you see any issues with it let me know!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/151693IqJTd7y81x6W2fh18sUCTWqaxKkrTI5NGRvcmI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Just use array formula in cell A1.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B1:B<>"",IF(B1:B="Project","Code",XLOOKUP(B1:B,Subledgers!$B$3:$B$58,Subledgers!$C$3:$C$58)),""))

Comment: this works perfectly! any recs on how to autofill column L (status) when the new row is added?

Comment: `when a new row is added to the worksheet:` Would a new row be added **below** or **above** the existing rows?

Comment: you can add below or above the existing rows. formula will be work fine.